# Temporal Clustering, with Constraints - Algorithms for doing so?

Tags: clustering

### Background to problem

I have a data set that consists of a matrix ( each row = a week's worth of data, cols = time in 24 hour clock, Monday to Friday inclusive) which is zero filled except for those hours per day, per week when an event occurs, marked by the value 1 in the relevant row/column matrix coordinate. I have summed down the columns to get a one-dimensional vector of number of counts per hour, per day over the entire data set. The goal is to cluster this count data so that a typically repeating event can be assigned to a time/day give or take a few hours error.

### Constraints

Each identified event occurs regularly every week, subject to the error mentioned above, so each "main" cluster size == no. of rows in the original matrix.

The number of "main" clusters can be determined by dividing the sum of the count vector by no. of rows, as the same number of events occur each week.

The remainder of the above division can clustered into a maximum of two "minor" clusters, which also repeat at approximately the same time(s) per week, but not necessarily every week. These two, "minor" clusters can be of different cluster sizes, but their sum must == the remainder of the division.

These two, "minor" clusters must be on either side of just one "major" cluster.

As this is repeating weekly data, it is periodic and so data on a Friday is closer to Monday's data than it is to Wednesday's data - the clustering must take this into account.

My question:- is there any algorithm/approach that can cluster this data, subject to the above contraints? A reference to an existing R package (or other language's package/module) would be ideal.

**Edit for clarification in response to comment**

Assume 100 week's worth of data, hence matrix size is 100 rows by 120 columns (5 days x 24 hours per day = 120). The sum of column #7 (7 a.m. Monday) is 20, sum of column #8 is 70 and sum of column #9 is 10. This totals 100 (the number of weeks in data), whichs means every Monday at 8 a.m. (+/- one hour) an event is said to regularly and repeatedly occur.

The clustering is to be done along the "time" axis so that a known and fixed number of events are identified throughout every week at specific times. The purpose of the clustering is to establish these specific times from the empirical data. Each event is the same type of event.

Comment: +1. I had a somewhat similar problem a while ago. I don't know of a way to properly impose the constraints, but obtained reasonable results by tuning the hyperparameters of the Mean Shift algorithm until I found clusters that mostly satisfy the constrains. I've written about it [here](http://eointravers.com/post/step-clustering/)

Comment: I don't quite understand this... your rows are the weeks, do you want to cluster them? Or rather days, hours or even events (which in that case of course would need to be represented differently). The data description sounds as if there is only one kind of event and data just indicate presence or absence, but "Each identified event occurs regularly every week" sounds like there may be more. May be in a given week they are all different, but the same events occur every week?